# Checking if a KClass is an object

Tags: kotlin

I have the following Kotlin code:

```
fun isObject(type: KClass<*>) = type.objectInstance != null

fun main() {
    println(isObject(emptyMap<Int, Int>()::class))
}
```

which produces the following errror:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$objectInstance$2 cannot access a member of class kotlin.collections.EmptyMap with modifiers "public static final"
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Reflection.java:361)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkAccess(Field.java:1075)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Field.java:416)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data$objectInstance$2.invoke(KClassImpl.kt:114)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$LazyVal.invoke(ReflectProperties.java:62)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.ReflectProperties$Val.getValue(ReflectProperties.java:31)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl$Data.getObjectInstance(KClassImpl.kt)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.KClassImpl.getObjectInstance(KClassImpl.kt:239)
```

I want my `isObject` function to work for any arbitrary `KClass` but I don't know how to do it without checking if the object instance is non null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Funny enough, I've only seen that happen with `private object`s, which is the case for `EmptyMap`. I'll look further into it. Anyway, in this case, you could try and see if the underlying java class has an `INSTANCE` field of the class type and is not `null`.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up just checking if the class was a Kotlin class first, but I'm going to keep this question open for a bit longer to see if there's a better way.

EDIT - also this happened sometimes when I did it with `java.awt.Rectangle` but that problem seems to have stopped

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some reflection overhead and that it only works with Kotlin/JVM then you can use my library [fluid-meta](https://github.com/fluidsonic/fluid-meta) for that:

```kotlin
fun isObject(type: KClass<*>) = Meta.of(type) is MObject
```

Use version 0.9.16 if you're still on Kotlin 1.3 and the library won't work otherwise.

It uses the hidden Kotlin metadata annotations added to each class generated by Kotlin. If these annotations get stripped in your project at some point (e.g. by an aggressive ProGuard) then you won't have that information at runtime anymore though.

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty cool, but I really just want like a one liner. Appreciate it anyways.